# Vim auto-indenting xml strangely

Tags: xml, vim, indentation, neovim

In vim (neovim), XML code is indenting strangely when attributes are put on their own lines, like so:

```
<test
    first="text"
    second="more text"
    third="last">
<foo
    a="a"
    b="b">
<bar />
</foo>
</test>
```

When I expect, and desire, this:

```
<test
    first="text"
    second="more text"
    third="last">
    <foo
        a="a"
        b="b">
        <bar />
    </foo>
</test>
```

This feels like none other than a bug to me. I could not find a plugin to address this. Perhaps there is something that I could add to my init.vim to correct this behavior?

EDIT:
The patch below almost fixes this issue, but does not correctly handle the following case:

```
<test
    first="text"
    second="more text"
    third="last">
    <foobar>
    </foobar>
    <foobar>
    </foobar>
</test>
```

EDIT 2:
Removing the `+ shiftwidth()` on line 90 solves all but this case:

```
<test
    first="text">
    <foobar>
    </foobar>
</test>
```

`<foobar>` should indent as shown above, because the tag spanning the first two lines is an opening tag, indicating that the next lines should be indented.

EDIT 3: For some reason, `<foo` is indenting twice with the patch. Expected:

```
<test>
    <foo
        a="a">
    </foo>
</test>
```

I know regex enough to play with it, but vim script makes this tricky.

EDIT 4:
Expected output should be:

```
<test>
    <foo
        a="a" />
    <foobar
        a="a" >
        <test>
        </test>
    </foobar>
</test>
```

`/>` should not indent the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not knowledgeable enough about XML to determine whether it's expected behavior nor can do proper tests, so I don't know if my solution is the best.

But if you suspect it to be a bug, then the best action would be to report<sup>1</sup> it on the official GitHub repository of XML runtime files: [chrisbra/vim-xml-runtime](https://github.com/chrisbra/vim-xml-runtime).

---

I managed to get your expected results by applying this patch<sup>2</sup>:

```
@@ -81,11 +81,16 @@
 endfun

 " [-- return the sum of indents of a:lnum --]
-fun! <SID>XmlIndentSum(line, style, add)
+fun! <SID>XmlIndentSum(line, style, add, ...)
     if <SID>IsXMLContinuation(a:line) && a:style == 0 && !<SID>IsXMLEmptyClosingTag(a:line)
         " no complete tag, add one additional indent level
         " but only for the current line
         return a:add + shiftwidth()
+    elseif a:0 && a:line =~ '^\s*<[^/]' && a:1 =~ '^\s*<[^/]' && a:1 !~ '>\s*$'
+                \ && getline(prevnonblank(a:2-1)) !~ '/\s*>\s*$'
+        return a:add + shiftwidth()
+    elseif a:0 && a:line =~ '^\s*</' && a:1 =~ '^\s*<' && a:1 !~ '>\s*$'
+        return a:add
     elseif <SID>HasNoTagEnd(a:line)
         " no complete tag, return initial indent
         return a:add
@@ -156,7 +161,7 @@
     " Get indent from previous tag line
     let ind = <SID>XmlIndentSum(pline, -1, pind)
     " Determine indent from current line
-    let ind = <SID>XmlIndentSum(curline, 0, ind)
+    let ind = <SID>XmlIndentSum(curline, 0, ind, pline, a:lnum)
     return ind
 endfun
```

Just copy the [indent file](https://github.com/chrisbra/vim-xml-runtime/blob/384ab377edddd5ce72c762244a58a131452f4b32/indent/xml.vim) to `~/.vim/indent/xml.vim` <sup>3</sup> and apply the change.

---

<sup>1</sup> You may link this answer in the issue
<sup>2</sup> Which is of quality of just a **temporary hack**
<sup>3</sup> I believe it's `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim/indent/xml.vim` in case of Neovim

Comment: This pointed precisely in the right direction. That patch almost does what I'm looking for, but when a new opening tag is added, it is giving an extra indent, and when a closing tag is added it is subtracting an extra indent. I'll edit my question above to illustrate.

Comment: @Christian What about now?

Comment: If I remove just your ```+ shiftwidth()```, that appears to satisfy every case except for one. So close! I gave a second edit above. I'm appreciating your help in this!

Comment: @Christian I don't understand? When I test the 3rd example I get the same result as expected. And if you remove `+ shiftwidth()` every other example should be broken, because this is the core part of this patch.

Comment: That is strange. I installed and tested it on regular vim, the + shiftwidth() indents it twice instead of once...

Comment: @Christian And now?

Comment: The 4th edit above fails after ```/>```. I think we will have it after that! Thank you!

Comment: @Christian Try now

Comment: Fantastic! Temporary hack, sure, but it does what I want! Thank you!